# apt update error in 4.13.0-kali-amd64 : "Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT"

Tags: apt, kali-linux

i am on the kali linux 4.13.0 amd64.

have a problem in running apt update with error showing.

```
# sudo apt update
Ign:1 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.3 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20171109-13:49] kali-rolling InRelease
Err:2 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.3 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20171109-13:49] kali-rolling Release
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.3 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20171109-13:49] kali-rolling Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove/uncomment the following line from your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.3 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20171109-13:49] kali-rolling InRelease
```

Because your `sources.list` [should contain only the following line](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories):

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

You can use the following command to overwrite your `sources.list`:

```
echo deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free > /etc/apt/sources.list
apt update
```

Comment: permission is denied using that code

Comment: @Morkser As root `su -` or using `sudo` (it is already installed on  your system) , type your root password then run the commands.

Comment: perfect its done

Answer (score 1):

Your repository for update is the cdrom.

Go [HERE](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories) to see how update your repository.

(maybe check your internet connections)

Comment: the major problem having is that im using ethernet wired connection since my internal wifi on the laptop is broken and having trouble finding driver for my realtek usb adapter

Comment: when i plug the usb driver it says this on ping

ping -c2 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable

Answer (score 0):

deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
above entry will do apt update from internet not from cdrom wrong solution.